# how to identify same columns from multiple tables in hive

Tags: hive, multiple-columns, multiple-tables

Hi I  have question about hive.

assume there are two tables t1 and t2.  t1 and t2 have columns with the same names.

t1:
emp_id, name,   salary, adress
1, a, 100, f

t2:
emp_id, name,   org,    product
1, trk, as,     dss

and when I want to  select these tables like

```
select *from t1,t2 join .....
```

hive birng me all columns but I am not able to identify which name columns come from which table.

please help, Thank you very much for your interest.

Also how to identify same columns from multiple tables in hive

Answer (score 0):

Use an alias instead of the *.

```
Select t1.ColumnName1 as [t1_ColumnName1],
       t1.ColumnName2 as [t1_ColumnName2],
        ... , 
       t1.ColumnNameN as [t1_ColumnNameN], 
       t2.ColumnName1 as [t2_ColumnName1],     
       t2.ColumnName2 as [t2_ColumnName2],
        ... , 
       t2.ColumnNameN as [t2_ColumnNameN] 
from t1 join t2  ...
```